# How to open href link in chrome to VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, href

Its my first time using VBA.
Apparently i need it to help me edit the available stocks from various products (gonna need to learn about looping) and that various products left me with different href stocks edit link
Is it possible to click on the href link and open it ?
heres the element
[image: href location]

heres the vba script

```
Sub AutoFill()

    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    
    obj.Start "chrome", ""
    obj.Get "https://siplah.blibli.com/login/merchant"

    obj.FindElementById("txt-email").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pass").Range("E20").Value)
    obj.FindElementById("txt-password").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pass").Range("F20").Value)
    obj.FindElementById("btn-login").Click
    obj.Wait (500)
    obj.FindElementByClass("modal-footer").Click
    obj.FindElementById("menu-product").Click

    obj.FindElementById("txt-product-name").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("31 CV").Range("E4").Value)
    obj.FindElementById("btn-search-product").Click

    
    
End Sub
```

Thank you before!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me to put copy the code rather than screenshot it! I made the post at 3am and probably didn't think it thoroughly and make a quick post.

Comment: It is helpful to also post the html using the snippet tool via [edit] rather than use image.

Answer (score 0):

Combining an attribute = value css selector with ends with operator to target href by the end if its href value, along with adding in the element className should be sufficient

```
obj.FindElementByCss(".link[href$='Slip']").click
```

---

Read about css selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: it works! im gonna read about the link you gave me to helps me know better. Thankyou very much! Appreciate it.